# Editing Newsfeed contents - SharePoint 2013

Tags: 2013, newsfeed, edit

I want to remove a document from my Newsfeed without removing it off the SharePoint site entirely.

It's basically just a blank txt document that has brief instructions in the document name for when someone navigates to a specific folder.  When it shows up on the Newsfeed it is confusing because it looks like "instructions" for the entire SharePoint site.

Is there a way to take it off the front page?

Thanks.